# how to convert string to binary integer file using command line under linux

Tags: linux, binary, integer

What i want is to take an integer represented as a string, for example "1234", and convert it to a file called int, containing a 32-bit big endian integer, with the value 1234.

The only way I have figured out to do this is something like

```
echo 1234 | awk '{printf "0: %08X", $1}' | xxd -r > int
```

which is a bit nasty!

Does anyone know a better way?

Comment: What's so nasty?

Its a command that works, use it

Comment: i prefer things like this to only require one tool, like the perl example below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok well seeing that mark williams seems to have gone awol i will post the corrected version of his answer

```
echo 1234 | perl -e 'print pack("N", <STDIN>); > int
```

Answer (score 5):

A slightly simpler way would be:

```
printf "0: %08X" 1234 | xxd -r > int
```

Answer (score 0):

this appears to produce the same output on my system. be sure to check `perldoc -f pack`.

`echo '1234' | perl -e 'print pack("nn", 0,<STDIN>);' > int`

Comment: so what I really want is pack("N",<STDIN>)

Comment: yeah, glad you caught my mistake and sorry i didn't take my own advice and consult perldoc first.